# Syntax Error in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to call my function `overwatch`. It should print out `bastion` and `lucio`.

My code looks right to me. However I'm getting a couple errors and I don't know why I'm getting an error.

```
def overwatch(hero1, hero2):
    print("hello " + hero1 "and " hero2)

overwatch(bastion, lucio)
```

Comment: Please edit your question title. It's a story that says nothing about the problem you are facing. Read the error message(s) you are getting. Tell us why you don't understand them.

Comment: Did you define `bastion` and `lucio`? Or, are they strings? If they are, use `overwatch(bastion, lucio)`

Answer (score 1):

You missed two `+` signs and quotes around your string literals.

```
def overwatch(hero1, hero2):
    print("hello " + hero1 + " and " + hero2)

overwatch('bastion', 'lucio')
```

Comment: Sorry. He seems new so I wanted to be gentle.

Comment: If "gentle" means people submit more questions of the same quality level, rather than learning how to write a question that's easy to answer, non-duplicative, and clearly asked, the site is worse off for that long-term.

Comment: You are right. I did not think about the long-term.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want bastion and lucio as a string variable, so you need to use `overwatch('bastion','lucio')`. Furthermore in your print statement you need to add a plus-sign:

```
print("hello " + hero1 "and "+ hero2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error, you are seeing is:

```
    print("hello " + hero1 "and " hero2)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and the solution is easy:

you should edit your code:

1) `print("hello " + hero1 + "and " + hero2)`

2) `overwatch("bastion", "lucio")`